# Regex matching alphanumeric with special characters

Tags: python, regex, django

I am trying to form an url in Django url pattern .

```
   url(r'^reports/(?P<bu>\w+|\W)/$', \
                LrsReportView.as_view(), name="elearning.lrsreports.region"),
```

The bu can be  a  string or string alphanumeric or alphanumeric with special character (except /)

But the above url is showing error for

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'elearning.lrsreports.region' with arguments '(u'Lawn&Garden',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

From the error I understood is this regex is not accepting the string having special character

Please help me out what might wrong here .

Comment: `WHat's wrong with my regex` -- How could one possibly tell you _what's wrong_ without knowing what was it intended to do?

Comment: IN error you can she url is not accepting the string having special character string is  Lawn&Garden

Comment: One error not related to regex is `name` is same for both.

Answer (score 2):

Your current RegEx will match:

- A string of one or more letters, numbers and/or underscores: [A-Za-z0-9_]+

OR

- A SINGLE character that is NOT a letter, number or underscore. [^A-Za-z0-9_]

You probably need something more like:

```
(?P<bu>[\w-]+)
```

This will match letters, numbers, underscore and hyphens.  Add any other special characters you want as well (inside the square brackets).  Remeber certain characters need escaping with `\` before them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$/